# Is there a parser generator that can use the Wirth syntax?

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, syntax, language-design

ie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirth_syntax_notation

It seems like most use BNF / EBNF ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction made by the Wikipedia article looks to me like it is splitting hairs.  "BNF/EBNF" has long meant writing grammar rules in roughly the following form:

```
  nonterminal = right_hand_side end_rule_marker
```

As with other silly langauge differences ( "{" in C, begin in Pascal, endif vs. fi) you can get very different looking but identical meaning by choosing different, er, syntax for end_rule_marker and what you are allowed to say for the right_hand_side.

Normally people allow literal tokens in (your choice! of) quotes, other nonterminal names, and for EBNF, various "choice" operators typically  | or / for alternatives, * or + for "repeat",  [ ... ] or  ? for optional, etc.

Because people designing language syntax are playing with syntax, they seem to invent their own every time they write some down. (Check the various syntax formalisms in the language standards; none of them are the same).  Yes, we'd all be better off if there were one standard way to write this stuff.  But we don't do that for C or C++ or C# (not even Microsoft could follow their own standard); why should BNF be any different?

Because people that build parser generators usually use it to parse their own syntax, they can and so easily define their own for each parser generator.    I've never seen one that did precisely the "WSN" version at Wikipedia and I doubt I ever will in practice.

Does it matter much?  Well, no.  What really matters is the power of the parser generator behind the notation.   You have to bend most grammars to match the power (well, weakness) of the parser generator; for instance, for LL-style generators, your grammar rules can't have left recursion (WSN allows that according to my reading).  People building parser generators also want to make it convenient to express non-parser issues (such as, "how to build tree nodes") and so they also add extra notation for non-parsing issues.

So what really drives the parser generator syntax are weaknesses of the parser generator to handle arbitrary languages, extra goodies deemed valuable for the parser generator, and the mood of the guy implementing it.